# Cannot Access server remotely through VPN tunnel when server is connected to am openVPN service

Tags: networking, router, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I created a VPN tunnel to my home LAN. The VPN Tunnel is successful because I can access my router's gateway.

I have `ssh` access to one of the servers on the network (`192.168.1.113`). I Tested this connection locally and it works. But, the server itself is using a VPN so its public IP address differs from the LAN's public IP.

The Issue is that I cannot ssh into `192.168.1.113` remotely with the VPN Tunnel switched on. Pinging the server results in:

```
PING 192.168.1.113 (192.168.1.113): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
--- 192.168.1.113 ping statistics ---
135 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

As a test, I switched off the VPN on `192.168.1.113` and it works. I can connect remotely with VPN tunnel. **But why is this happening?** If I tunnel to my LAN that should mean I am another device on my LAN. No different than being physically there right?

### Some Details

- Router: Archer C7 with OpenVPN Server
- `192.168.1.113` using openVPN with a protonVPN configuration file

### Update

When access the router gateway remotely from tunnel, My remote pc is not visible under LAN network devices. But it is visible under VPN Connections with this info:

- Remote IP: `84.185.102.210`
- Assigned IP: `10.8.0.6`
- The assigned IP is part of the openVPN subnet/netmask: `10.8.0.0/24`

### Update 2

Looking at `tcpdump` with `sudo tcpdump -eni any icmp` while pinging `192.168.1.113` from vpn tunnel is showing:

```
12:29:21.027220 eth0  In  ifindex 2 e8:48:b8:e1:57:1a ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 104: 10.8.0.6 > 192.168.1.113: ICMP echo request, id 45097, seq 32, length 64
12:29:21.027357 tun0  Out ifindex 1063 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 104: 192.168.1.113 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 45097, seq 32, length 64
12:29:22.004265 eth0  In  ifindex 2 e8:48:b8:e1:57:1a ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 104: 10.8.0.6 > 192.168.1.113: ICMP echo request, id 45097, seq 33, length 64
12:29:22.004411 tun0  Out ifindex 1063 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 104: 192.168.1.113 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 45097, seq 33, length 64
```

### Update 3

using `arp -a` on Mac machine to check other devices on a network, does not show any other devices when I am on the tunnel. Trying the same command when directly on LAN shows the Server I want to connect to.

Comment: When you SSH into the server while ProtonVPN is disabled, what IP address does the server see you as coming from? Does it see you as connecting from 10.8.0.6, or does it see you as coming from 192.168.1.1, or something else?

Comment: @user1686 it sees me as connecting from `10.8.0.6`. So from the IP assigned by the VPN server.

Comment: and if I am connecting from home/LAN then it sees me as `192.168.1.143` i.e. an IP address given to the machine by the DHCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why is this happening? If I tunnel to my LAN that should mean I am another device on my LAN. No different than being physically there right?

You're *not exactly* on your LAN. The VPN is a separate subnet which is interconnected with your LAN, but nevertheless a "distant" network from the server's point of view.

The server always has a local route for `192.168.1.0/24` (the network it is directly in), but most likely does not have one for `10.8.0.0/24` – it relies on the default route to reach that (as it still leads through the same router either way).

When the server is connected to the VPN, however, its primary default route is no longer through the Archer but through the VPN instead. So whenever the server receives a packet from 10.8.0.6, **it tries to respond through the VPN** (which discards the packet at some point). You can see in tcpdump that the "ICMP Echo Reply" packets *are* being sent, but they're being sent through the "tun0" device instead of Ethernet.

Basic IP routing is per-packet, not per-connection, and responses are *not* automatically routed the same way that the initial packet came from – the server routes its outbound packets independently of any inbound packet that prompted them. (In other words, routing can be asymmetric.)

In your case, the simplest way to avoid this is to define a specific route for 10.8.0.0/24 on the server, so that packets to this destination will always go through the Archer even if the VPN is up. (More-specific routes always have priority over less-specific ones; you don't need to set specific metrics or anything.)

In more complex setups (e.g. if the client address was unpredictable and not limited to just the VPN /24) you could use iptables or nftables rules to apply a "mark" to inbound connections and have `ip rule` choose one of several default routes depending on whether the outbound packet belongs to a connection marked as local or not.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you. So I need to add a route in the routing table, something like `ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.1`. With `192.168.1.1` being the router's gateway?

Comment: Yes, although you'll probably want to add it somewhere more permanent (e.g. the netplan or networkd config).

Comment: as you pointed out that is not a permanent solution. The route does not persist across restarts. Can you outline the steps needed to make it persist? Thanks